# Is an algorithm that stitches together various algorithms "good enough" material for IEEE Trans?

Tags: publications, journals, ieee

I have worked on a paper which utilizes concepts from signal processing and machine learning, and then implements them in a low-cost embedded system. Since the work was more on the implementation side, it required less mathematics and more engineering. Furthermore, since I was using hardware from a particular company which suited my application the most, among other contenders in peripherals and price, the implementation is really hardware-dependent. Finally, I cannot seem to find similar work. In that way, it is a bit novel. Is this something which will be acceptable for say, *IEEE Transactions in Industrial Electronics*?

Answer (score 5):

"Stitching together" some existing algorithms is not necessarily bad, if the combination is both valuable and non-trivial. It can be argued that *a lot* of today's research in computer science is mostly stitching together ideas that have existed for a long time. Further, I am a huge opponent of the notion that it is somehow better / scientifically more valuable to come up with your own (almost always inferior) algorithms for well-known standard problems just so that one can claim to have a higher "novelty".

That being said, it is of course hard to answer your question without knowing the concrete work. As a rule of thumb, read through a number of back issues of your selected journal. If all of them seem to have a much broader contribution than what you have in mind, your idea may be *too small* (but don't let the [impostor effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome) get you, either).